# Factory fails after changing name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have a factory that work's fine when its symbol is `:notification_event` but when I change the name to `player_notification_event` it fails with the error

> uninitialized constant PlayerNotificationEvent.

Also, my other factory `:property_notification_event` is failing as well, with the error

> uninitialized constant PropertyNotificationEvent.

#### failing factories

```
  factory :player_notification_event do
    notification_eventable_type 'Player'
    association :notification_eventable, factory: :player
    unread_count 1
    last_notif_unread_count 0
    last_email_message_count 0
    last_email_time 5.hours.ago
    last_notif_time 3.hours.ago
  end

  factory :property_notification_event do
    notification_eventable_type 'Property'
    association :notification_eventable, factory: :property
    unread_count 1
    last_notif_unread_count 0
    last_email_message_count 0
    last_email_time 5.hours.ago
    last_notif_time 3.hours.ago
  end
```

#### failing specs

```
  let(:player_notification_event) { create :player_notification_event }
  let(:property_notification_event) { create :property_notification_event }

  it 'sends email to player' do
    player = player_notification_event.notification_eventable
    allow(UnreadMessagesMailer).to receive_message_chain(:player_email, :deliver_now!)

    described_class.perform
    expect(UnreadMessagesMailer).to have_received(:player_email)
  end

  it 'sends email to property' do
    property = property_notification_event.notification_eventable
    allow(UnreadMessagesMailer).to receive_message_chain(:property_email, :deliver_now!)

    described_class.perform
    expect(UnreadMessagesMailer).to have_received(:property_email)
  end
```

#### passing spec

```
  let(:player_notification_event) { create :notification_event }

  it 'sends email to player' do
    player = player_notification_event.notification_eventable
    allow(UnreadMessagesMailer).to receive_message_chain(:player_email, :deliver_now!)

    described_class.perform
    expect(UnreadMessagesMailer).to have_received(:player_email)
  end
```

#### passing factory

```
  factory :notification_event do
    notification_eventable_type 'Player'
    association :notification_eventable, factory: :player
    unread_count 1
    last_notif_unread_count 0
    last_email_message_count 0
    last_email_time 5.hours.ago
    last_notif_time 3.hours.ago
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default of `factory_bot` is to look for a class with the same name as first argument in `factory`, if you don't pass a `class` explicitly (check [official guide](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/file/GETTING_STARTED.md)). Try this:

```
factory :player_notification_event, class: NotificationEvent do ...
```

Comment: This is explained in the [GETTING STARTED](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/file/GETTING_STARTED.md) section of the documentation.

Comment: In addition, you may wish to consider using a `trait` here, instead of defining a second factory.

Comment: @TomLord What am I getting wrong here? https://gist.github.com/antarr/8b9b3d0fd4ec7b70150f200b4ce24639

Comment: Isn't it just unfortunate naming, where your trait has the same name as factory inside it? First thing I'd try would be changing the trait's name.

Answer (score 2):

You can use inheritance here instead of duplicating the entire factory.

> [...] it's good practice to define a basic factory for each class with only
>   the attributes required to create it. Then, create more specific
>   factories that inherit from this basic parent. Factory definitions are
>   still code, so keep them DRY.
>   https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/file/GETTING_STARTED.md

```
factory :notification_event do
  unread_count 1
  last_notif_unread_count 0
  last_email_message_count 0
  last_email_time 5.hours.ago
  last_notif_time 3.hours.ago

  factory :player_notification_event do
    notification_eventable_type 'Player'
    association :notification_eventable, factory: :player
  end

  factory :property_notification_event do
    notification_eventable_type 'Property'
    association :notification_eventable, factory: :property
  end
end
```

Since the model class is derived from the parent `factory :notification_event` you don't need to manually specify it.